# VMware player: could not find component on update server

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player

I installed `MacOS 10.15 "Catalina"` on `VMWare Workstation Player` in `Windows 10` as host.
Now I want to install `VMWare Tools` so I clicked `Player -> Manage -> Install VMware tools` but I got this error:

[image]

I am using this version of player:

```
VMware® Workstation 15 Player
15.5.2 build-15785246
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download the latest version here:
https://packages.vmware.com/tools/releases/latest/windows/x64/

Notice this folder is for `Windows x64`, browse for your `OS`, if different.

Download to your `VM` and install... then close the `VM` to get everything in sync.